# How to split the rows in the array using match()?

Tags: javascript, arrays, string-matching

I have a matrix containing arrays of rows.

```
let matrix=[['hello'],['world']];
```

I'm duplicating rows.

```
matrix=matrix.map(x=>String(x).repeat(2)).map(x=>x.match(new RegExp??))
```

I want to get

```
[['hello','hello'],['world','world']]
```

Answer (score 2):

If you want to duplicate the arrays, you can use concat

```js
const matrix = [
  ['hello'],
  ['world']
];
const res = matrix.map(a => a.concat(a))
console.log(res);
```

Or given that you have an array of arrays and you want to get an N number of entries instead of 1:

```js
const matrix = [
  ['hello'],
  ['world']
];
const res = matrix.map(a => Array(4).fill(...a));
console.log(res);
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code wouldn't work. First there's no `Array::repeat()` method, second there's no any sense to use `RegExp::match()` to duplicate an array, third you're trying to assign to a const variable. Use simpler tools.

Since you overwrite the original array you can just mutate it:

```js
const matrix = [
  ['hello'],
  ['world']
];
// push array into itself thus duplicating it
matrix.forEach(arr => arr.push(...arr));
console.log(matrix);
```

That would be definitely faster than overwriting with a new array:

[image]

```html
<script benchmark data-count="5000000">

// @benchmark The fourth bird
{
let matrix = [
  ['hello'],
  ['world']
];
matrix = matrix.map(a => a.concat(a))
}

// @benchmark Alexander
{
const matrix = [
  ['hello'],
  ['world']
];

matrix.forEach(arr => arr.push(...arr));
matrix;
}
</script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/gh/silentmantra/benchmark/loader.js"></script>
```

Comment: Your benchmark doesn't demonstrate anything here though

Comment: @JaDa could you elaborate? what are you talking about?

Comment: Because whatever benchmark tool you use, it looks like you've set it to run 5 million times and it delivers milliseconds as an answer. That part is just noise.

Comment: @JaDa if you know a better way to benchmark please explain shortly. there's duration differences in my benchmark and they tell which option is faster definitely. that's the goal - to determine which is option is faster, no more

Comment: No the ultimate goal here is to answer his question. Showing a statistic and going "look one number smaller" without considering the actual numbers together with an answer is just noise.

Comment: @JaDa my answer matches the OP's goal and more performant than creating a new array. I don't see any benefits in your comments

Comment: @JaDa yes, it doesn't mean anything as i told there's only difference between the code variants that matters

Comment: @JaDa it's planned to improve it by displaying percentage differences while the milliseconds only for reference only

Comment: Also if you want a more realistic example. Here instead of timing doing the same thing 5 million times, let's do the same thing on an array of 5 million. 
https://codepen.io/inabahare/pen/OJrNZgQ

bird: 1960 ms,
alex: 1606 ms

A whooping 300 milliseconds (not seconds, milliseconds) difference on my end.

Comment: @JaDa i'm aware of it, and there should be 2 benchmarks, one with small data and the  second with big data. working toward to combine both into 1 tool